# Printing every block of data containing 11 lines

Tags: linux, sed

I've got a file with text divided into blocks of 11 or 10 lines (each block is separated by a new line). I want to extract only the 11-line blocks. Is there any sed command which would allow me to specify 11 patterns (each for every line) and print them (the whole block) only if there was an exact match?

Cheers

Comment: The 'separated by a new line' means that there's a blank line separating the blocks of data?  Yes, it can be done if the choice is between 10 and 11; use the N command often enough (10 or 11 times) and check if the last line is empty.  But it ain't pretty.  And if there could be 9 (or 12) lines as well, then it gets decidedly trickier, I think.

Comment: Yes, there's a blank line separating the blocks of data. I've got only 10 and 11-line blocks. Could you sketch how it should look like (this N command solution)?

Comment: The `awk` solution you've accepted is much simpler to understand and much more robust.  While you can do it in `sed`, I really don't think it is appropriate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know that you asked for sed but GNU awk makes this task easy:

```
awk -F'\n' -v RS= 'NF==11' file
```

`-v RS=` tells awk to use empty lines as its record separator.

In awk, each record is divided into fields.  `-F'\n'` tells awk to use the newline character as the field separator.

`NF==11` tells awk to print the record only if it consists of 11 lines.

Comment: It's ok now. Thank you so much! :)

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -nr ':a;N;$G;s/\n+$//;Ta;s/[^\n]+/&/11p' file
```

Use the `-n` grep-like option and `-r` extended regexp option.

Append lines to the pattern space until an empty line. If the pattern space then contains 11 (or more) lines print it.

N.B. On the edge case that the last line may or may not be empty add a newline.

For exactly 11 lines only:

```
sed -nr ':a;N;$G;s/\n+$//;Ta;/^([^\n]+\n){10}[^\n]+$/p' file
```